# Why is the anova p-value on these series of numbers not significant

Tags: anova, p-value, interpretation

I have three different samples (three replicates per sample) and lots of variables (1000+)

This variable in particular had the largest VIP number from an Orthogonal signal correction PLS-DA of these three different samples. Usually I log2 transform these, but for this example I did not (it doesn't seem to make a big difference)

```
A  <-  c(7.98E8,4.88E8,1.68E8,2.21E7,5.37E7,1.41E7,4.21E8,8.03E7,3.67E6)
condition <- factor(c(0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2))
variable  <- data.frame(raw=A,condition=condition)
```

when I look at the means they seem really different (especially 0 vs 1) It’s almost an order of magnitude

```
tapply(variable$raw,variable$condition,mean)

        0         1         2 
484666667  29966667 168323333
```

and the box plot

```
boxplot(variable$raw ~variable$condition)
```

[image: box plot]

when I try a oneway test

```
oneway.test(variable$raw~variable$condition)

data:  variable$raw and variable$condition
F = 2.945, num df = 2.000, denom df = 2.702, p-value = 0.2095
```

the p-value is not even close to being significant.

Why is this? Is it the large variance, small number of samples? Maybe there is something I don’t understand about anova because the means seem really different across these samples. I do check that the data seems normally distributed so a parametric test seems reasonable. Maybe there is a different test I should be using?

Comment: With such a small number of samples and the large variance you have very low power to test for differences among groups. Also keep in mind that you have no power to test for normality.

Comment: Just to muddy the waters a bit :-), redo your analysis based on the *logarithms* of the dependent variable: `oneway.test(log(variable$raw) ~ variable$condition)`. The distinctly smaller p-value provides some justification for your original intuition.

Comment: I usually test for normality be looking down my data. For example I make a histogram of all the values for every variable (over 1000) for each sample (usually a small number). Is this not correct?

Comment: whuber- Fascinating, I must be doing something wrong, because when I do this `A2<-log2(A)`  
`variablelog<-data.frame(log=A2,condition=condition)`  
`oneway.test(variablelog$log ~ variablelog$condition,var.equal=TRUE)`  I get a p-value that is much bigger p=0.14 than doing in your way

Comment: @Brett: That's probably because you used `var.equal=TRUE` When variances are different on original scale, they will be on log scale also. Try a boxplot of the log transformed values.